# Protractor screenshot of open select box not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, protractor, screenshot

Next in my list of protractor woes:

I have a case where I click on a select element and hover over the empty choice at the top, and grab a screenshot of that. Or at least I try. It grabs the screenshot, no errors, and moves on. However, not with the select box open. Just a closed select box.

What am I missing? Here's the snippet:

```
createPage.userid.click();

// Take screenshot of page
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
  writeScreenShot(jpg, 'screenshots/deleteUser.jpg');
});
```

I've tried a few other things I've found on here like trying to click it open, and then hovering the option, etc. but nothing works.

EDIT:
Something I've noticed that may have to do with this. When I let the browser run behind an open other window, when the dropdown opens, it shows up in front of said window, totally detached from the browser. Which reminded me of one of those key concepts I learned when I was a wee web developer that dropdown menus are given a z-index pretty much above everything else when they open.  Could it simply be that protractor can't see the open dropdown because it's so "high up"?

Comment: I think it is a timing thing again, perhaps. Try prefacing the function you are in with "async." Then place the word "await" before createPage.userid.click(). That way you can be sure the click has completed before you take your screenshot. By the way, then you also get say let jpg = await browser.takeScreenshot() and move to writeScreenShot as its own next line without the whole then function thing.

Comment: or if that does not work or looks confusing, first find an element in the select box for which you have an identifier or locator, then say something like the example at http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf

Comment: basically what would appear to be happening is the click has not had the desired effect before the snapshot is taken. But it is worth learning at least one of the above two approaches rather than adding sleep (which will either slow things down more than needed or will sometimes fail if your picture, say, loses the race).

Comment: It does look confusing. Sorry. I looked at the link, and my issue is that when I try to reference protractor.ExpectedConditions, my script has no idea what I'm talking about. I'm not sure how to properly use async/await. Maybe I should go learn that. FTR, I tried the sleep as well, and it didn't work at all. :(

Comment: Also, the screenshot of the open select box is not the first or the last thing that I'm doing inside the larger "it" block. Will the await before this click prevent everything before it from happening or just from getting past that point in the script until it happens?

Comment: sadly, the async/await didn't do it either.

Comment: EDITED QUESTION

Comment: I believe await waits for your command to complete before moving on. The stuff before it can keep happening. Depending on your setup, you may need import {
    ExpectedConditions,
} from 'protractor'; and may not need the protractor. preceding ExpectedConditions. I am not sure about your theory in the edited question. I guess we will await others' thoughts.